# PostgreSQL user listing

Tags: postgresql, privileges, psql

I want to get a list of users for a certain database in psql - for example "template0". Who are the users? Or for "template1" database: - who are the users there?

Already tried:

```
\du+  -- no database is Listed not Users
Select * from "pg_users";  -- no database is listed
```

Answer (score 79):

User aren't actually, "for the database", they're for cluster and are given different permissions to access databases. To list users `\du` should do, but you need to be connected. Something like

```
psql template1 -c '\du'
```

from the command line prompt should do. (or `\du` from psql prompt *when you are connected to the database*).

Answer (score 13):

You must understand that in PostgreSQL users are **per database cluster**. @Michael already demonstrates how to get a list of those.

So, unless you restrict permissions for a particular databases explicitly with [`REVOKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-revoke.html) and `GRANT`, all users in the cluster have basic access to any database in the cluster.

To determine, whether a specific **user** actually has a certain privilege ('CONNECT') for a database:

```
has_database_privilege(user, database, privilege)
```

More about [privilege functions in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS-TABLE).

To determine all specific privileges for a specific **database**:

```
SELECT datname, datacl
FROM   pg_database
WHERE  datname = 'mydb';
```

You get `NULL` for `datacl` if no specific restrictions apply.

---

In addition to that you can restrict access per database and per user in the [**`pg_hba.conf`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file. That's on a lower level. The user cannot even connect, if `pg_hba.conf` won't let him, even if the database itself would allow access.

Comment: Also note, on recent versions you can grant/revoke CONNECT privileges to db's.

Answer (score 6):

To list roles/user

select rolname from pg_roles;