# Change logged user to export table from postgres > CSV

Tags: postgresql, csv

I'd like is to export a table in a postgres server to a local folder (CSV).

I'm using pSQL console, and the command:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM <nameTable>) TO 'C/temp/<nameTable>.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

When I run it, the console shows "ERROR: must be superuser to copy to or from a file".  All I've configured is the Server properties (server-user, etc) when I installed pgAdmin III (and I think I did enter a Superuser).

So how can I:

- Know who the current logged user is, and whether he's a superuser?
- Change the logged user?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926389/postgresql-user-listing

Comment: Sorry Patel, but I can't see the connection on your reply. I'm newbie to postgres. I've found this export feature on pgAdmin: http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/export.html    but I can't find where it is located on the pgAdmin III interface.

Comment: Go to **PgAdmin III ---> Plguins --> PSQLConsole** Then write **\du** it will list all the users with its roll permission.

Comment: You want `\copy` not just `copy`; see `\?`

Comment: Thanks all, working now. The quickest system I've found is, following Ptel, this:
PgAdmin III ---> Plguins --> PSQLConsole
SELECT * FROM <tablename>
Finally, File>Export> <choose dir>
This probably isn't available in previous versions.